# Display result in group of rows and sum each groups value

Tags: php, mysql

I do not have much experience with PHP/MySQL. I have a table with 3 fields: `id`, `particular`, and `amount` as shown below.

```
id   particular   amount
1    Fees         5000
2    Fees         3000
3    Bill         9000
4    Fees         4000
5    Bill         3000
6    Expense      2000
7    Fees         1000
```

I want to show the data in groups as well as the sum of each individual group, like so:

```
particular   amount
Fees         5000
Fees         3000
Fees         4000
Fees         1000
**Total        13000**
Bill         9000
Bill         3000
**Total        12000**
Expense      2000
**Total        2000**
```

i try this query `SELECT SUM(amount), particular FROM sale_expense GROUP BY particular` and it added all the values, but it is not showing in the group as I need to display the data

Comment: Have you looked at the `GROUP BY <columns> WITH ROLLUP` option in the MySQL documentation?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT particular, id, sum(amount) amount
FROM TableName
GROUP BY particular, id WITH ROLLUP
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c448d/2)

Comment: this is your query resultParticular Amount
Balance
 
Balance
 
Balance
 
Rent
 
Rent
 
Salaries
 
Salaries
 
Salaries
 
Telephone Bill
 
Telephone Bill
 
Telephone Bill

Comment: What's your question? The rows with null id are the subtotals for the groups.

Answer (score 2):

try this sql:

```
SELECT particular, SUM(amount) AS total  FROM tablename GROUP BY particular
```

This should give you the total of each group.

UPDATE:
try this

```
$sql = "SELECT particular, SUM(amount) AS total  FROM tablename GROUP BY particular";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE particular = '".$row['particular']."'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )){
        echo $row2['particular']. "  ".$row['amount'];
        echo "\n";
    }
    echo "Totol: ".$row['total']."";
}
```

Comment: Yes i can add all the values but i want to display groups as well.

Comment: No result found. nothing displayed.

Comment: ya sure i checked all fields name and table name as well.

Comment: Loop inside loop can affect speed. .. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can union the queries together:

```
select particular, amount
from ((select id, particular, amount
       from sales_expense se
      ) union all
      (select 99999 as id, concat('Total: ', particular), sum(amount) as amount
       from sales_expense se
       group by particular
      )
     ) t
group by particular
order by id
```

Comment: i try you query but its not working as i want to display data.

Comment: I don't understand.  The query should be returning the data that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
( SELECT 
    particular, 
    amount  
  FROM sale_expense )
UNION
( SELECT 
    CONCAT(particular," - total") AS particular, 
    SUM(amount) AS amount 
  FROM sale_expense
  GROUP BY particular )
ORDER BY particular ASC
```

Comment: I corrected to second query " AS particular". I think this should work.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') UNION(SELECT CONCAT(particular,' - total') AS particular, SUM(amount) AS amou' at line 1